# FreeBSD jail and patch-levels

Tags: freebsd, jail

I am a newbie server manager and trying jails. It's too hard to configure it. So I decided to use `ezjail` utility. It seems working, but I got an issue.

When I installed my FreeBSD box, it was `9.0-RELEASE`. After I upgrade it, it became `9.1-RELEASE-p7`.

The problem is `ezjail` tried to download FreeBSD distro from FreeBSD FTP site. And it failed because ezjail wanted `9.1-RELEASE-p7` and the site has only `9.1-RELEASE`.

I tried forcing download by manually specifying `9.1-RELEASE` path, but created jail doesn't work with this message.

```
Configuring jails:.
Starting jails: cannot start jail "example_com":
.
Error: Could not start example.com
  You need to start it by hand.
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work. What is the recommended way to configure a jail for beginner?

P.S.
My test VM is using DHCP and doesn't have static IP and domain name. can it cause this problem?

### Update

I succeeded to install a jail using `bsdinstall jail $JAIL_NAME`. Anyway, I have no idea how it's done...

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe add any relevant `/var/log` messages? You're trying to start a jail and it's failing right? What do the patch issues and version issues have to do with that?

Comment: @inetplumber As I added on update, I did it using `bsdinstall`, and now I am not sure which file is really relevant to `ezjail`. I'm sorry, and I will update this QA as I get better result.

Comment: check out `/etc/rc.conf` to see if `bsdinstall` auto made some config examples you can copy and crib for a manual configuration in the future. also http://forums.freebsd.org/ is THE go to place for freeBSD related stuff. I would highly recommend it (they can be rough - but it's worth it).

Comment: "So I couldn't fetch it due to different patch-level version number." <-- You couldn't fetch what?? What program are you trying to fetch something with? The jails are configured in `/etc/rc.conf` as inetplumber mentioned. Configuring them really isn't hard at all, what were you having problems with exactly?? This really isn't a question so much as a rant about something not working...

Comment: @ChrisS `ezjail` tries to download FreeBSD distro from FreeBSD FTP site. And it failed because `ezjail` wanted `9.1-RELEASE-p7` and the site has only `9.1-RELEASE`. It was the message I saw.

Comment: @ChrisS I updated my question to describe better.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to `qjail`, and it's working magically. All I need is only FreeBSD disc.
I think difference of patch-level may cause some problem, but currently, I satisfied on `qjail`.